# C# Box-API [net_WebHeaderInvalidControlChars] received when downloading a file with Korean filename or when the file is corrupted

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, box-api, box, boxapiv2

I received the following error when downloading from Box server:

```
    InnerException  {System.ArgumentException: [net_WebHeaderInvalidControlChars]
Arguments: 
Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=4.7.60408.0&File=System.Net.dll&Key=net_WebHeaderInvalidControlChars
Parameter name: name
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndGetResponse>b__d(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)}  System.Exception {System.ArgumentException}
```

Shown below is the code snippet.

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler) { MaxResponseContentBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue })
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

    try
    {
        var fileResponse = await client.GetAsync(requestUrl, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);                    

        if (fileResponse != null && fileResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            return await fileResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        else return null;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error in getAsync, " + e.StackTrace);                    
        return null;
    }

}
```

Note that this only happens for files with Korean (non-English) filenames and corrupted files. For image files and non-corrupted files, I was able to download successfully. (Example of corrupted file is a word or ppt file that shows an error msg when opened).

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue in windows phone 8. 
I tried 
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);

I tried 
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(url,UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

I tried IRestResponse from RestClient

All resulting in exception with empty value and inner exception **net_WebHeaderInvalidControlChars**.

The problem was that the user agent passed from windows client was not recognized server side. As a result, one from the returned response headers, was making .Net to crash in a lower level and the response could not be processed.

Adding **NativeHost** as the recognized UserAgent fixed the exception